# What is NSTemporaryObjectID_default?

Tags: ios, objective-c, introspection

In an iOS Objective-C application, I use `objc_getClassList` to get the list of classes.

Sometimes (not always, I can't find the pattern yet) I see a class that appears in this list:

`Bundle: com.sample.myApplication - Class: NSTemporaryObjectID_default`

What is this class and how did it end up within my bundle identifier?

Comment: I think iOS wasn't able to resolve one of the identifiers in runtime.

Comment: Do you use core data?  It looks like an internal class used to provide `objectID`'s for not-yet-persisted objects.

Comment: I don't use it directly, but it could be that one of the frameworks I use use it.